# Python Syntax - more than one function done on a variable in a row

Tags: python, syntax

It's been a while since using Python and I wanted to make sure my syntax was ok.

I'm writing a function, that if an input parameter is 1, I convert an image to grayscale, then convert it to a floating point, and then normalize intensities.

If the code is wrong that's ok - I'm here to learn about proper syntax and making sure I'm writing clean, nice easy

```
if representation == GRAY_SCALE:
    new_image = rgb2gray(image)
    image_float = new_image.astype(np.float64)
    return image_float/NUMBER_INTENSITIES
```

Or do I go ahead and save space by doing the following:

```
if representation == GRAY_SCALE:
    new_image = rgb2gray(image)
    return (new_image.astype(np.float64))/NUMBER_INTENSITIES
```

Thank you!

Comment: The first one has better self-documentation. The difference is minor, however.

Comment: Though not necessarily a problem in this case, one thing to be aware of is that each variable you declare takes up more space in memory. If memory is (or might be) an issue, I would use the latter. Otherwise, I would use the former as it's clearer what's happening, as @timgeb stated already

Comment: I think this is more of a personal opinion, but I would say if you  would use the variable image_float another time, use the variable, if not, than use the smaller version. I prefer the second one, because it looks cleaner.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off topic because it's primarily opinion based, but FWIW, I think #1 is clearer, to me it's clearer what you're doing.